# paraview MFIX crash on Mac

Tags: osx-lion, paraview

I just installed Paraview 4.0 on Mac OsX (10.7.5).  When I open an output.res file produced with MFIX on Linux, the paraview crashes.
I have no problem opening the same file on Linux with paraview.

Any suggestions how to make it work on Mac?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sample data that you could share? It may be some invalid memory access issue in the reader which could be easy to track with a sample dataset.